# Android studio 2.1.2 - error:cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.string)

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.grghajj1.memecreator1;

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.TextView; 



public class BottomPictureFragment extends Fragment {

private static View topMemeText;
private static View bottomMemeText;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup     container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_picture_fragment, container, false);  

    topMemeText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.topMemeText);        
    bottomMemeText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomMemeText);  

    return view; 
}


public void setMemeText(String top, String bottom){
      topMemeText.setText(top);
      bottomMemeText.setText(bottom);
}
```

compiler showserror: cannot find symbol method setText(String) and cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String).

pls could some one let me know how to solve this problem

Comment: Declare `topMemeText ` and `bottomMemeText ` as `TextView ` instead of `View` because `setText` method is in `TextView` instead of in super class(View) of TextView

Comment: remove View and use TextView instead

Comment: Yes this was the missed part, problem resolved, thank you @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: Yes this was the missed part, problem resolved, thank you @Tapanparmar

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the TextView's as View, change these lines:

```
private static View topMemeText;
private static View bottomMemeText;
```

to :

```
private static TextView topMemeText;
private static TextView bottomMemeText;
```

Comment: Yes this was the missed part, problem resolved, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **View** to **TextView** as setText() method is use for TextViews and not for Views, Gradle can not find the appropriate method you are trying to call so it's your problem. Just try to declare components as they are and avoid Parent class declarations such as Views.